# Extremely slow setup:upgrade on magento 2.4

Tags: azure, mariadb, magento2

everyone!
I'm using Magento 2.4 Open Source with remote MariaDB database version 10.3.
Problems begin when I run `setup:upgrade` in the cli, it takes like 1.5 hours to complete hanging after "Cache clear complete".
I thought it was frozen and looked if there are any active database queries using the `show full processlist;`

Turns out it was running a queries like this

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'captcha_log'
```

for every table in the DB taking around 1-10 seconds each.

If I run this query myself I get the following output:

```
+-----------+------+-------+----------+----+--------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
|Name       |Engine|Version|Row_format|Rows|Avg_row_length|Data_length|Max_data_length|Index_length|Data_free|Auto_increment|Create_time        |Update_time|Check_time|Collation      |Checksum|Create_options|Comment             |Max_index_length|Temporary|
+-----------+------+-------+----------+----+--------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
|captcha_log|InnoDB|10     |Dynamic   |0   |0             |16384      |0              |0           |45088768 |NULL          |2021-07-26 10:57:13|NULL       |NULL      |utf8_general_ci|NULL    |              |Count Login Attempts|0               |N        |
+-----------+------+-------+----------+----+--------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+----------------+---------+
```

It took 10 seconds to complete this query! The `innodb_stats_on_metadata` if off by default.

Is it a problem with my MariaDB configuration or i missed some important thing in my Magento config? BTW I'm using Azure database for MariaDB.

I'm really interested to know how can I debug issues like this.

Comment: If you manually do the same `show table status like 'captcha_log'` does it take the same time? Can you edit the question to include the output and which MariaDB version you are using?

Comment: @danblack no problem)

Comment: One more [profile point](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-profile/) if I may. `set profiling =1; SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'captcha_log'; show profile; set profiling = 0`.

Comment: A broader record maybe achieved with [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-query-store) maybe. I also looked at the [Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L1191) code and it looks odd as to why the `show table status` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by moving to a different database solution.
You may choose a more expensive general db type (we were testing basic), or host small VM with MariaDB.